# Is it possible to generate a JAD file that already contains the JAR URL?

Tags: eclipse, java-me, codenameone

When using CodenameOne to produce builds for J2ME, the resulting JAD file always contains a blank entry for the MIDlet-Jar-URL attribute.  Is there a way of specifying the URL in the project, so I don't have to edit the JAD by hand after every build?  I'm using Eclipse.

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to edit this by hand? You can install onto the device directly from the build server.

Comment: Hi Shai, thanks for your response.  I want our customers to be able to update the application using the built-in update mechanism on their phone, so I need the MIDlet-Jar-URL attribute to be set to the URL of the latest JAR.  When I get the result.zip back from the CodenameOne build server, the JAD always has that attribute empty.

Comment: The links on the Codename One site are for development time only and not for redistribution. Since you need to download the file anyway editing it before uploading to the server isn't that much of a difference.

Comment: Agreed, it isn't much of a difference, but it is one more step that the developer has to remember to complete before each release.  Not to worry.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering for completeness sake: this isn't currently supported.